# Blur effect on window background image

Tags: wpf, xaml, background, blur, effects

I have a window with image as background. On that window I also have buttons and other controls.

This is my style for that window:

```
<Style x:Key="MyWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\myImage.png" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <BlurEffect Radius="20" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The problem is that the blur effect is applied to the whole window and not just the background image. So, my buttons are also blurred, which is not what I want. I want just the image background to be blurred, and not the buttons. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using an ImageBrush for the Background of your window, add an `Image` control as first (lowest) element to the top-level container of your window, and set the Effect there:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="Images\myImage.png" Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="20"/>
            </Image.Effect>
        </Image>

        <!-- other UI elements -->

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you really need a Background Brush, you might use a `VisualBrush` instead of an ImageBrush like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Image Source="Images\myImage.png">
                        <Image.Effect>
                            <BlurEffect Radius="20"/>
                        </Image.Effect>
                    </Image>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ...
</Style>
```

In order to crop the border of the blurred background brush, you could adjust the `Viewbox` (which by default is given in relative units) like so:

```
<VisualBrush Viewbox="0.05,0.05,0.9,0.9">
```

Of course the precise values depend on the absolute size of the image. You might also specifiy the Viewbox in absolute units by setting `ViewboxUnits="Absolute"`:

```
<VisualBrush Viewbox="0,0,1024,1280" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
```

Comment: This works, but it adds a black border of about 5 milimeters around the blurred image, and makes the image 5 mm smaller so that there's room for the border. How can I remove the border?

Comment: I have no idea where that border comes from. It is certainly somewhere in your application. Which approach did you try?

Comment: The second one, with the VisualBrush.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be the outside part of the blurred area that adds to the total dimensions of the brush. I'll try to fix that. Maybe the other approach is just simpler anyway.

Comment: The size of the window is 1024x1280. It's fixed. So, the size of the background image is the same.

Comment: Please see my edit. You may play around with the Viewbox values. It may look even better if you also crop the outer 10 pixels or so by setting `10,10,1004,1260`.