# Show different background for transparent buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

We have a design requirement such that transparent buttons (with white text) are overlayed on a scenic background image. But here's the hard part, and my dilemma...

While the background image should be clear and visible OUTSIDE the image borders, the area INSIDE the buttons (the overlayed area) should be a blurred area of the background image. The idea is to make it easier for users to see the white text inside the button.

I'm a novice in XAML and even more unfamiliar with how to perform such complex styling. I have a starting point for the overlay layout, but this code does not attempt to solve the problem. It's simply a button over an image.

Any ideas or help on how to blur the area under the image?

```xml
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,12" Visibility="{Binding SignedIn, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=False}">
  <Image Source="backgroundImage.png" Height="136" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
  <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button x:Uid="SignInBtn" Content="SIGN IN" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButtonStyle}"      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding SignInCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding          LoadingResults, Converter={StaticResource NotBoolConverter}}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to do this in a Windows Phone 8.1 app. Image effects are not supported in either Windows Phone Silverlight or in Windows.UI.Xaml.

The typical and easy solution would be to dim (rather than blur) the image by setting the Button's background to a partially transparent brush.

```
<Button Background="#7F000000" </Button>
```

If you want to put a bit more work into it you can crop the area of the bitmap behind the button, run your blur transform on it (take a look at the [Lumia Imaging SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.adjustments.blurfilter.aspx)) and then set the new, blurred image to the button.

Comment: I have strong opinions that I will likely choose one of the above options. If I do, I'll certainly mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Effects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2008/05/12/using-effect-in-wpf-part-2.aspx).

In addition, see if you can leverage this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904292/blur-effect-on-window-background-image):

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Image Source="Images\myImage.png">
                        <Image.Effect>
                            <BlurEffect Radius="20"/>
                        </Image.Effect>
                    </Image>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
...
```

Comment: I'm definitely going to try this. Thanks for the quick response. If this ends up working out, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.